# Where's the trailhead to Blueberry Hill?

Tags: nova-scotia

[The leftmost image](http://www.hikecapebreton.ca/cape-breton-highlands-trails/blueberry-hill/) purports the trailhead to be next to Cap Rouge:

[image]

1. Where's it on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.7315308,-60.9229641,3a,75y,204.69h,80.52t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sHPMPCAiGpfuiceCLCwCc7Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en)? I can't spot it.

[image]

2. Where do trekkers park? I see no parking lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This appears to be the trailhead.](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.7308578,-60.9233106,3a,75y,108.97h,75.61t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s6berSECzF2kQtTnaxu3_fQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

I found the location from this description:

> The trail is starts just across the road from the Le Rouge look-off / interest area along the Cheticamp side of Cabot Trail. Parking is available in that parking lot. The trail itself is still currently unmarked but easily visible once you cross the road.

[image]